# Unusual function declaration in Verilog

Tags: function, verilog, system-verilog

To try to understand, I looked for some code on the internet and found the following declaration of what I suppose to be functions, and that I don't understand at all.

```
sext #(.inwidth(1), .outwidth(32))  scc_sext_i0(
                  .i0(paw_0_i0_outport0[32]),
                  .o0(scc_sext_i0_o0));

combine2_wn #(.inwidth0(32), .inwidth1(32))  scc_combine2_wn_i0(
                  .i0(paw_0_i0_outport0[31 : 0]),
                  .i1(scc_sext_i0_o0),
                  .o0(scc_combine2_wn_i0_o0));


combine2_wn #(.inwidth0(32), .inwidth1(32))  scc_combine2_wn_i1(
                  .i0(scc_combine2_wn_i2_o0[31 : 0]),
                  .i1(scc_combine2_wn_i2_o0[63 : 32]),
                  .o0(scc_combine2_wn_i1_o0));
```

My questions are the following:

1. Are these really functions mapping?
2. If yes, they are not defined in any other lower level .v file (and no library is included either in the top-level file). So what is their use?
3. What does `#` symbol mean?
4. What does `.inwidth(32)` mean? input of 32 bits? (impossible to find on the internet...)
5. If yes, the `combine2_wn` blocks should have only 2 inputs, why is there an output mapped each time?

More generally, are these any kind of concatenation functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are most likely module instantiations, not function calls.

You should have a module named `sext` and another named `combine2_wn` declared in files somewhere in your Verilog search path.

`#()` means you are assigning values to `parameter`s inside the named modules.

There is a parameter named `inwidth` in the `sext` module.  You are assigning it a value of 1.

There are plenty of references on the web.  Look at the verilog wiki site.